# How can I use the Winforms WebBrowser control in a webapp?

Tags: multithreading, webbrowser-control

I have developed a library to manipulate HTML to conform to our needs using the WebBrowser control, however I need this library to work on a web app and not a winforms app.  The main issue I get is this:

*"ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment."*

I understand this is because the WebBrowser control needs to be ran in a STA Thread, but obviously a web app isn't an STA environment.  Its a server side process though so its not in a page itself.  Any ideas on how I can get round this?  I considered setting the *AspCompat="true"* attribute on the *Page* tag of a hidden page and running it from that but I would rather a more elegant solution.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiate and perform your work in a new thread upon which you have explicitly set the ApartmentState via [SetApartmentState()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate.aspx).